# Implement type casting from one class to another

Tags: c++, oop

Assuming I have two classes which are not related by inheritance. e.g:

```
class MyString
{
    private:
        std::string str;
};

class MyInt
{
    private:
        int num;
};
```

and I want to be able to convert one to another using regular casting e.g `MyInt a = (MyInt)mystring` (where `mystring` is of `class MyString`).

How does one accomplish such a thing?

Comment: One doesn't, because that's not a sensible thing to want.

Comment: I assume you convert `std::string` to `int` via `str.size()`, and `int` to `std::string` via interpreting the bytes of the `int` as `char`s and appending them together?  Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: You can [overload the conversion operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281334/c-overloading-conversion-operators).

Comment: @KerrekSB I could think of plenty of scenarios where you'd want that kind of conversion.

Comment: C++ already has enough automatic conversions as it is. Make your conversions explicit. Add named, free-standing conversion functions like `MyString toMyString(MyInt const& my_int)` and `MyInt toMyInt(MyString const& my_string)`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl What advantages does an explicit function used for conversion have over operator overloading of the casting?

Comment: @Jonathan It assures you that the compiler doesn't convert "by mistake" when you least expect it. However, in C++11 you can have [*explicit* conversion operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).

Comment: @Jonathan: In addition to @vsoftco's comment, it's much like with the pros and cons of `auto`. Being explicit makes code easier to read and easier to search.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The conversion needs to make sense first of all. Assuming it does, you can implement your own conversion operators, like in the example below:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class MyInt; // forward declaration

class MyString
{
    std::string str;
public:
    MyString(const std::string& s): str(s){}
    /*explicit*/ operator MyInt () const; // conversion operator
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyString& rhs)
    {
        return os << rhs.str;
    }
};

class MyInt
{
    int num;
public:
    MyInt(int n): num(n){}
    /*explicit*/ operator MyString() const{return std::to_string(num);} // conversion operator
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyInt& rhs)
    {
        return os << rhs.num;
    }
};

// need the definition after MyInt is a complete type
MyString::operator MyInt () const{return std::stoi(str);} // need C++11 for std::stoi

int main()
{
    MyString s{"123"};
    MyInt i{42};

    MyInt i1 = s; // conversion MyString->MyInt
    MyString s1 = i; // conversion MyInt->MyString

    std::cout << i1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/981f34ddd868a4b8)

If you mark the conversion operators as `explicit`, which is preferable (need C++11 or later), then you need to explicitly cast, otherwise the compiler will spit an error, like

```
MyString s1 = static_cast<MyString>(i1); // explicit cast
```